# ConstraintLayout TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view, android-constraintlayout

The two TextViews overlap each other inside the ConstraintLayout, like it is shown in this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ3CO.png).

How to solve this problem?

Follows the sample code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you add `android:singleLine="true"` to both `TextView`s?

Comment: Sorry, I was the first question, the title was wrong, right is "In the constraint layout, two multiline TextView contents overlap".

Comment: In your 'Preview' you show on the right-hand-side that text has been truncated and is fixed to one line - this is *NOT* what you want?

Comment: @Jack Parkinson But I need to show multiple lines of content

Comment: From the preview it looks like the margins are pushing your `TextView`s up and overlapping them. Try making them smaller.

Comment: I reduced the margins of TextViews, on Android Studio preview them looks better, but run on the phone still overlap.

Comment: This problem seems to be resolved in 1.1.0-beta1 of ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"` to `textView1` to separate the two. I am not sure why you are seeing what you are seeing, but this will work.

Comment: This can solve my problem. In my case, not only `textview2` to set `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"`, `textview1` also need to set `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"`,  otherwise `ConstraintLayout` height calculation may be wrong.